# How to migrate/run legacy j2ee applications from JDK 1.3.1 to JDK1.6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a legacy application (petstore1.3.2) that I have managed to deploy and run on JBOSS 3.2.3 (J2SDKEE1.3.1 and JDK1.3.1).

I tried to run it on JBOSS 4.2.3 also with J2SDKEE1.3.1 but with JDK6 in order to run another tool on the server which I couldn't deploy on JBOSS 3.2.3. The problem is JBOSS 4.2.3 has JDK 1.6 or JDK6 as a minimum requirement.

Once I deploy petstore1.3.2 I get errors which I believe are being caused by JDK6 (even though the code is compiled using JDK 1.3)

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Populate exception occured :null
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.tools.populate.PopulateServlet.doPost(PopulateServlet.java:122)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.tools.populate.PopulateServlet.doGet(PopulateServlet.java:106)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.signon.web.SignOnFilter.doFilter(SignOnFilter.java:154)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.encodingfilter.web.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:77)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118 cannot be cast to com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.signon.user.ejb.UserLocalHome
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.tools.populate.XMLDBHandler.endElement(XMLDBHandler.java:150)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.tools.populate.PopulateServlet.populate(PopulateServlet.java:162)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.tools.populate.PopulateServlet.doPost(PopulateServlet.java:118)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.petstore.tools.populate.PopulateServlet.doGet(PopulateServlet.java:106)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.signon.web.SignOnFilter.doFilter(SignOnFilter.java:154)
com.sun.j2ee.blueprints.encodingfilter.web.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:77)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Comment: Whats the sense of it? JBoss 4.x is way to old. Current versions are Wildfly > 10. Latest version is 18. (The community version of JBoss was renamed to Wildfly years ago). But it will not support old j2ee applications anymore. It has to be refactored.

Comment: I'm studying the code therefore I can't touch it (minimal changes) and I also need to run it to get the execution traces and analyze them